# How could write a web page that detect unkown javasscriptinterface object webview of android device?

Tags: javascript, android, interface, webview, detect

I want Write a web page for service to Android device.
before every thing i want to check is there any  javasscriptinterface object used in the WebView or not... if there is any detect that.
i am writing my new Exclusive security method for develop safe page.
All help appreciated.

Comment: "Exclusive security method" sounds more like you're writing a security exploit to me... Could you elaborate on how your security method would work?

Answer (score 0):

The `JavaScript Interface` is added by the `WebView` as an `Object` of the `window` component.

So you can test JavaScript presence by doing :

```
if (window.MyJavascriptInterface)
{
    // Interface present
}
else
{
    // No Interface
}
```

Here is the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript)

Comment: thanks for answering but this is not working when we do not know the name of our object that represent Javascriptinterface.... my web is not for especial program ... i want develop a web site that could handle every android program with WebView and javascriptinterface object ... thanks again my friend

Comment: I don't know if I understood well your problem, but I think you can't achieve what you want to do... The `JavaScript Interface` can have any name. If you do not control the name, I don't see any solution...